# how to make sure a variable is set to a value and it can if tested in catch block

Tags: c#

I am writing a proof of concept with a simple requirement where I load an account, make a webservice call to initiate payment and if it is successful update the account balance.

The intention of following code is to make sure some reversal is done if web service call was successful in taking money out of customer' bank but account could not be saved due to concurrency issue. However, I have this strange issue that even if response is successful, the **if test in catch block** returns false and the exception is re thrown?

**edit begin:**

if `response.IsSuccessful` is `true` and `ConcurrencyException` occurs at `accountService.Save(account)` line, shouldn't `currentStatus` be equal to **WEBSERVICE_SUCCESSFUL** ?

**edit end:**

This is a web application and call to **Process()** is triggered by front end. Am I missing anything obvious? Any help would be really appreciated.

```
function void Process(Account account, string param1, decimal param2) {
    string currentStatus = "START";
    try
    {
        log("Begin web service call"); 
        var response = webservice.Call(param, param2);
        log("End web service call");

        if(response.IsSuccessful)
        {
           currentStatus = "WEBSERVICE_SUCCESSFUL";
             //update account balance 
             accountService.Save(account);
        }
        else
           {
            // do something else
           }
    }
    catch (ConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        log("Error concurrency..");
        if( currentStatus == "WEBSERVICE_SUCCESSFUL")
            //do reversal 
        else
           throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use transactions?

Comment: is accountService good? is account good?

Comment: Have you checked if accountService != null ?

Comment: Are you sure `accountService.Save(account)` throws only `ConcurrencyException` ? Because you don`t have catch block for catching any other exception...!!

Comment: While this doesn't directly address your question, you should use `throw;` instead of `throw ex;` in order to keep propagating the exception.  Using `throw ex;` will cause existing stack trace information in the exception to be lost.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I tried to use transactionScope. I am/will be using NHibernate as ORM and using Session per view session management. I couldn't get it work with TransactionScope when session per view was used. I always had some transaction issue. Google search asserts there were some known issues if the proper opening and closing of session and TransactionScope was not done. This is only place where I would need distributed transaction capability so I dropped the idea and reverted to basics.

MBen and John Blade, yeah both account and accountService are good.

Comment: @PrateekSingh I removed other catch blocks but when I looked at Log4Net output it's actually being catched in ConcurrencyException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you are looking for a **Transaction**.  You should take a look at the [System.Transactions()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx) namespace which has been designed *specifically for problems like this*.

For example what would happen in the scenario when you server crashes at the exact point between taking payment and updating the balance?

Using the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class not only are you abstracting away dealing with transactions yourself but it will automatically escalate to be managed by the [MSDTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator) (if available) which will deal with server crashes such as this.

Everything below (such as Exceptions) will also automatically rollback the transaction.

Take a look at [Writing a Transactional Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229973.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I tried to use transactionScope. I am/will be using NHibernate as ORM and using Session per view session management. I couldn't get it work with TransactionScope when session per view was used. I always had some transaction issue. Google search asserts there were some known issues if the proper opening and closing of session and TransactionScope was not done. This is only place where I would need distributed transaction capability so I dropped the idea and reverted to basics.

Looks like I have to find a way to fit both TransactionScope and NHibernate Transaction together in Session per view.

Answer (score 0):

`accountService.Save(account)` function may throw another exception which the catch block doesn't catch them. In this case try to replace `ConcurrencyException` by `Exception`

Comment: I removed the generic Exception Catch block from the code snnipet but I do have it and it's being caught at ConcurrencyException's catch block.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ta Quans answer - it might be worth having both levels of exceptions caught as it seems your exception handler is specific to concurrency issues:

e.g.

```
    try 
    { 
       some code....
    }
    catch (ConcurrencyException ex) 
    { 
        log("Error concurrency.."); 
        if( currentStatus == "WEBSERVICE_SUCCESSFUL") 
            //do reversal  
        else 
           throw; 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        log("Some other error: " + ex.Message);

        if( currentStatus == "WEBSERVICE_SUCCESSFUL") 
            //do reversal  
        else 
           throw; 
    }
```

Comment: My problem is not the type of Exception but the line where if(CurrentStatus == "WEBSERVICE_SUCCESSFUL") returns is __false__ even if response.IsSuccessful is true and some error occurs at the accountService.Save(..)